# ¿Cómo extraer un determinado patrón de un string en Python?

Tags: python, string, lista

Tengo las siguientes listas:

```
Lista1 = [54,67,43,12,34]
Lista2 = [32,56,76,88,35]
Lista3 = [16,36,74,57,64]
```

y tengo un string el cual contiene unas operaciones a realizar con las listas:

```
expresion = "(Lista1 * Lista1) + (Lista2 - Lista3^2) + (Lista2^3)"
```

El objetivo es **analizar la expresión y realizar el calculo respetando los paréntesis** (es decir, **resolver primero las operaciones dentro del paréntesis**), para ello estuve analizando de implementar del **modulo re** de python algún método que me permita extraer el contenido de los paréntesis para luego ser resuelta y luego continuar con el procedimiento

> las operaciones que se pueden encontrar dentro del paréntesis entre 2
> listas son: *,+,/,- Dentro del paréntesis se pueden encontrar entre 1
> o mas Listas, y cada lista dentro del paréntesis pueden estar elevadas
> a algún exponente
> **No debo usar Numpy para las operaciones**

Estuve buscando como establecer el patrón o bien buscar una alternativa mas eficiente, pero no estoy encontrando solución. ¿Cuál es la mejor alternativa para poder realizar los cálculos de los paréntesis primero y luego el resto de la operación?

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que resulta de multiplicar/dividir dos listas?

Comment: @CandidMoe vendría a ser multiplicar o dividir cada elemento por de las listas de forma paralela, es decir cada posición se multiplica o divide con el elemento de la otra lista de la misma posición,

Comment: ¿La expresión puede mezclar escalares con lista? Por ejemplo, 2 * Lista1

Comment: La solución no es en absoluto obvia. La forma estándar de abordar expresiones aritméticas que puedan contener paréntesis es crear un árbol de parseado. Pero insisto, esto no es trivial. Ya que el enunciado tiene toda la pinta de ser un ejercicio de clase, sería importante conocer qué nivel tienes o se te supone. Imagino que el objetivo del ejercicio no será la creación de un parser genérico, sino adaptado a este caso concreto, en el que las expresiones están bastante limitadas. Aún así, no lo veo sencillo

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas un lexer, algo que examina la expresión y la divida en sus componentes (tokens). Con eso puedes construir un *parser*, que analice la lista de tokens, los valide como expresión válida, produciendo una estructura que refleje el orden correcto de las operaciones. Para este problema, probablemente bastara con dos stacks: uno para valores y otro para operaciones pendientes.

Finalmente, necesitas un evaluador que recorra esa estructura realizando las operaciones mismas.

Este es un lexer simple que te puede servir de punto de partida. No valida que la expresión sea valida, ni tiene chequeo de errores. En particular, supone que todos los operandos son del tipo `ListaN`.

```
def lexer(expresion):
    """
    Convierte una expresión en una lista de tokens:
    (Lista1 * Lista1) + (Lista2 - Lista3^20) + (Lista2^3)
    :param expresion: Una expresion algebraica
    :return: Una lista de tokens
    """
    tokens = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(expresion):
        car = expresion[i]
        if car in '()+-*/^': # Operaciones y parentesis
            tokens.append(car)
            i += 1
        elif car == ' ': # Saltar espacios en blanco.
            i += 1
        elif expresion[i:i+5] == 'Lista': # Una variable ListaN
            tokens.append(expresion[i:i+6])
            i += 6
        else:  # Cualquier otra cosa es un escalar
            j = i+1
            while expresion[i:j].isnumeric():
                j += 1
            j -= 1
            tokens.append(expresion[i:j])
            i = j

    return tokens
```

**Demo**

```
expresiones = [
    'Lista1',
    'Lista1 + Lista2',
    '(Lista1 + Lista2) / Lista3',
    '(Lista1 / (Lista2 - Lista3))',
    '(Lista1 * Lista1) + (Lista2 - Lista3^24) + (Lista2^3)']

for exp in expresiones:
    print(exp, "=", lexer(exp))
```

produce:

```
Lista1 = ['Lista1']
Lista1 + Lista2 = ['Lista1', '+', 'Lista2']
(Lista1 + Lista2) / Lista3 = ['(', 'Lista1', '+', 'Lista2', ')', '/', 'Lista3']
(Lista1 / (Lista2 - Lista3)) = ['(', 'Lista1', '/', '(', 'Lista2', '-', 'Lista3', ')', ')']
(Lista1 * Lista1) + (Lista2 - Lista3^24) + (Lista2^3) = ['(', 'Lista1', '*', 'Lista1', ')', '+', '(', 'Lista2', '-', 'Lista3', '^', '24', ')', '+', '(', 'Lista2', '^', '3', ')']
```